# How do I color — some but NOT all — text in a sentence, in HTML5?

Tags: html

My corporation  has a discussion forum that uses HTML. I'm uncertain if this is HTML5, and if it also uses CSS.

`<font color="red">Color this red.</font>` failed, probably because ["The  color attribute is not supported by HTML5"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-font-color-attribute/).

`<p style="color:red;">Red paragraph text</p>` ***worked***. **But this code DOESN'T answer my question** — because I want just some but NOT ALL text, in a sentence, coloured. I don't want the whole para. colored!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p>Horses like <span style="color:blue">sober</span> penguins.</p>`

> The span tag is used for grouping and applying styles to inline elements.

https://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_span_tag.cfm